# Don't seem to be able to show an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

To prove: If x < $0$, then $x^2 +x>0$.

I have tried the following:

If $x<0$, then $-x>0$, which implies $(-x)(-x)>0$. This is, $x^2 > 0$.

Since $-x>0>x$, if follows that $x^2-x>x^2>x^2+x$. Particularly, it holds that $x^2>x^2+x$...

But I don't find a way to guarantee that $x^2+x>0$. Is this the right path?

Comment: It's not true. Consider $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The roots of $x^2+x$ are telltale

Comment: You're right, I didn't consider that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+x=x^2+x + \tfrac14-\tfrac14=(x+\tfrac12)^2-\tfrac14$, so this expression is negative when $x$ is close to $-\tfrac12$. This disproves what you want to prove.